# Adding new element to json file php

Tags: php, json

Here's my code:

```
$user = new User($_POST['login'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['name']);
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'));
$users[] = $user->toArray();
file_put_contents('users.json', json_encode($users));
```

When the json file is empty, user gets added correctly, but when a user already exists in json file, when I try to add another user using this code, it just replaces the existing user.

Comment: Do a `print_r($users)` please when there is something in $users

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, the problem is that "$users = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'));"  equals NULL, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just needed to set 'associative' to true in json_decode:

```
$users = json_decode(file_get_contents('users.json'), true);
```